# PowerBI - Specifying More Than 8 Colours in a Theme

Tags: powerbi, themes, legend, powerbi-desktop

I've created line and clustered column chart in PowerBI.

This chart consists of 13 columns and ideally I'd like each of these column to be of different colour but it's not possible as in *View-> Themes -> Customize Current theme* it's possible to choose only 8 colours.

So the result is that 8 columns have a correct colour (set in theme settings) but remaining 5 columns are of random colours that aren't in the theme settings.

So the question is if it is possible to somehow loop the 8 colours from theme settings to have only these 8 colours on the chart? So that 9th column would've the colour of first column, the 10th column would've the colour of 2nd column etc. ?
I'd like to avoid changing these columns' colours manually as I would have to make these changes really often.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add more than 8 colours if you manually edit the json.

```
{
       "name": "St Patrick's Day",
       "dataColors": ["#568410", "#3A6108", "#70A322", "#915203", "#D79A12", "#bb7711", "#114400", "#aacc66"],
       "background":"#FFFFFF",
       "foreground": "#3A6108",
       "tableAccent": "#568410"
   }
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-report-themes